# How to prevent wrong values in an initializer list?

Tags: c++, constants, initializer-list, valueerror

When you write a constructor, you have the opportunity to test the values of the arguments from out of range or other unwanted situations in its body.

```
class a
{
  int b;
public:
  a(int c)
  {
    if(c < MIN_ALLOWED || c > MAX_ALLOWED)
    {
      // Take some measure
    }
    else
    {
      b = c;
    }
  }
};
```

But when you're dealing with const members, they should be initialized by means of an initializer list, so, in this case, how to prevent unwanted values?

```
class a
{
  const int b;
public:
  a(int c) : b(c)
  {
    // How to control "c" value?!...
  }
};
```

Comment: You can use a ternary operator in the intializer list to test the value assigning to the const member. However, const members in classes should be avoided. It doesn't work with much of the STL and is generally hard to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class a
{
    const int b;
public:
    a(int c) : b((c < MIN_ALLOWED || c > MAX_ALLOWED) ? throw std::logic_error("bad") : c)
    {
        // How to control "c" value?!...                                                                        
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a function:

```
class a {
    int const b;

public:
    a(int const c)
        : b { initializeB(c) }
    {
    }

private:
    static int initializeB(int const c)
    {
        if (c < MIN_ALLOWED || c > MAX_ALLOWED) {
            // Take some mesure
            return -1; // example
        }
        return c;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate the verification and modification of the variable to a function.

```
class a {
 public:
  a(int c) : b(ValidateAndTransformInputParameter(c)) {}
 private:
  const int b;
  int ValidateAndTransformInputParameter(int d) const {
    if (d < 100) {
      d = 100;
    }
    return d;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three major ways:

1. Chain the validation with the comma-operator:

   ```
   a(int c) : b(validate(c), c) {}
   ```

   Remember that the initializers are executed strictly depth-first, in declaration order, ignoring virtual inheritance.
2. Using the ternary operator:

   ```
   a(int c) : b(validate(c) ? c : throw 0) {}
   ```

   This needs the least amount of folderol if it's really a one-off.
3. Using a transforming and validating class or function:

   ```
   a(int c) : b(process(c)) {}
   ```

Optionally, they might be combined with ctor-chaining, especially if more than one result comes from processing the inputs:

```
private:
    struct process {
        ...
    };
    a(process x) : b(x.b), c(x.c), d(x.d) {}
public:
a(int c) : a(process(c)) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers are good and work... but lest we forget, you can also do:

```
class a
{
    public:
        a(int c) : b([=]() -> int {
            if (c < MIN_ALLOWED || c > MAX_ALLOWED)
                throw std::logic_error("b");
            return c;
        }()) {}
    private:
        int b;
```

};

It looks awful in my opinion though, having a lambda in an initializer list, but it's still possible.